# XmlSerializer returns null

Tags: c#, xml, xmlserializer

I have an XML that i am trying to serialize to a class but i am unable to fathom why the object is null.
[null object](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFHFz.png)

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns0:vendResponse xmlns:ns0="http://mynamespace.co/ns0">
         <ns0:sequence>234532532221</ns0:sequence>
         <ns0:CId>0</ns0:CId>
         <ns0:RefId>202675454545453434343</ns0:RefId>
         <ns0:origAcct>20.00</ns0:origAcct>
         <ns0:destAcct>00087646564</ns0:destAcct>
         <ns0:responseCode>0</ns0:responseCode>
         <ns0:responseMessage>Successful</ns0:responseMessage>
      </ns0:vendResponse>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>



var contentStream = File.ReadAllText("response.xml");
        Envelope resultEnvelope = new Envelope();            
        using (var stringReader = new StringReader(contentStream))
        {
            using (XmlReader reader = new XmlTextReader(stringReader))
            {
                var serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
                resultEnvelope = serializer1.Deserialize(reader) as Envelope;
            }
        }
```

the soap Envelope class generated in VS using paste XML as classes:

Comment: check Envelope class properties.

Comment: Could you please show the Envelope, Body and vendResponse classes?

Comment: i couldn't add the class because its long and it will violate stackoverflow rules. but u can see it here : https://bun.filedit.ch/nXtNAivfQOFCOXLPrdKC.cs

Comment: I could not reproduce works fine for me: https://dotnetfiddle.net/ICB8Bj

Comment: @KlausGütter vendResponse  is not null but its elements are null

Comment: No, see updated dotnetfiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/gRrQr3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.Data;

namespace ConsoleApplication23
{

    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(FILENAME);
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Envelope));
            Envelope envelope = (Envelope)serializer.Deserialize(reader);


        }
    }
    [XmlRoot(ElementName = "Envelope", Namespace = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/")]
    public class Envelope
    {
        [XmlElement("Body")]
        public Body body { get; set; }
    }
    public class Body
    {
        [XmlElement(ElementName = "vendResponse", Namespace = "http://mynamespace.co/ns0")]
        public VendResponse vendResponse { get; set; }
    }
    public class VendResponse
    {
        public string sequence { get; set; }
        public string CId { get; set; }
        public string RefId { get; set; }
        public string origAcct { get; set; }
        public string destAcct { get; set; }
        public int responseCode { get; set; }
        public string responseMessage { get; set; }
    }
 
 
}
```